# How do I change my iCloud password when it’s stolen?

Tags: icloud, password, find-my-iphone

My iPhone was stolen. And they have my iCloud password and changed it. Is there a way I can change it without it going to the iPhone or change it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start at https://iforgot.apple.com/. You may need to know the answers to your security questions and access to the email account associated with your AppleID.